# Pagination is not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

My code for controller:

```
public $paginate = array(
        'paramType' => 'querystring',
        'limit' => 3,
    );


$this->paginate['Comment'] = array(
                           'conditions' => array('Comment.post_id' => $this->params['id']));

$this->set('comments',$this->paginate('Commant'));
```

When I do

```
pr($this->paginate['Comment'] = array(
                               'conditions' => array('Comment.post_id' => $this->params['id']))); exit;
```

The output is 
Array

```
(
    [conditions] => Array
        (
            [Response.claim_id] => 4
        )

)
```

But instead of finding comment related to post it shows all post from db

Once I tried

```
pr($this->paginate['Comment'] = array(
                                   'conditions' => array('Comment.id' => $this->params['id']))); exit;
```

And the Result was same

```
Array

    (
        [conditions] => Array
            (
                [Response.id] => 4
            )

    )
```

Can any one suggest me why pagination is not woking

Comment: You don't need to index your `$this->paginate` array with the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
public $paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring',
    'limit' => 3,
);
```

in controller

```
$this->set('comments',$this->paginate('Response',
                           array('Response.claim_id' => $id)));
```

in your function

And define Paginator component in controller

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to index your `$this->paginate` array with the model.

As you are using a Controller variable `$this->paginate` means that it doesn't need to be indexed using the model.